# Drawing TL094 Quad Comparator in Schematic

Tags: schematics, comparator, drawing

Quick question on drawing schematics, when you are drawing a quad comparator into a schematic (such as the TL094), do you use the comparator symbol four times with the IC label by it or do you use the IC symbol with the power, inputs and outputs labeled? Does it matter or is it all just a matter of preference?

Comment: If you can create your own parts then you can have it both ways. Normally a CAD program has them as separate sections, same as quad op-amps, but you can custom make one as a single package. Make sure your parts footprint is accurate.

Comment: Which one will make your schematic more clear? Do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create your own parts then you can have it both ways. Normally a CAD program has them as separate sections, same as quad op-amps, but you can custom make one as a single package.

I have Orcad and often I will copy and save a part under a new name, as there are a zillion quad op-amps out there. By default they are 4 separate sections with each part number having the same pin out, but different noise specs, etc.

Since you may have to custom make many parts anyways, it is easy to make a quad op-amp as a single package.

Make sure your parts footprint is accurate, that is an SOIC package vs. a 14 pin DIP package.

Comment: +1 the only thing that might catch you out if you split them into four parts is the hidden power pins, especially if you try to use each section on a different set of rails. If you do use different rails in the design you also need to make sure the PCB designer doesn't switch "gates" to make it more routable.

Comment: @Trevor_G. There is an option to hide or make power pins visible in Orcad. The problem with hidden pins is they are named pins, so that is a problem anyways, especially with a star topology for ground. The router wants to run them all together. So I made a 4 and 6 point ground symbol and footprint...lol.

Comment: Yup, it a bit more complicated than say logic gates that all have the same supplies.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer showing the individual comparators (or op-amps, or gates or...) as that makes it much easier to see and understand the function of the circuit.

Showing a quad comparator as a 14 pin box requires finding a datasheet and much tracing of wires to determine how the things within it are connected (same with any multi-part IC).